# Loop in recursive function

Tags: python, recursion

For some algorithm I found it convenient to define a recursive function that looks something like this:

```
def f(l):
    for i in range(2):
        if len(l)>=1:
            print(l+[i])
        else:
            return f(l+[i])
f([0])
```

But the behavior is different from what I expect. What it does is print

```
[0, 0]
[0, 1]
```

But I would expect it to print

```
[0,0]
[0,1]
[1,0]
[1,1]
```

Somehow the nested function has access to the variable i, and instead of starting a new loop with some different variable, it simply continues on counting with this variable i. I don't understand why Python does this.

My (vague) question is therefore why does Python do this, and is there some obvious modification to my code that would give the output I initially expected?

Comment: you never change `l` and it starts at `len(l) == 1` which means it prints twice and exists: your `else` is never triggered.

Comment: How does an input of `[0]` lead to the output you described? Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: @Keiwan Any valid input (a list) may be supplied to that function and it will output the above, or the supplied list twice with a 0 then a 1 tacked on. I suspect this is not what he intends.

Comment: I suspect you just need to change `>= 1` to `> 1`. Then it will use the `else` clause the first time it's called, and the `then` clause in the recursion.

Comment: Right, I tried to simplify the function to illustrate my problem better. Turns out I simplified it too much. I meant something more along the lines of:
`def f(l):
    for i in range(3):
        if len(l)>1:
            print(l+[i])
        else:
            return f(l+[i])
f([])`
What I wanted is for such a function on the first level to call f([0]), then f([1]) and so on. The problem I now see is that `return` breaks the for loop. 
Should I edit my question? It seems I can't delete it, but in it's current form it's indeed a bad question.

Answer (score 1):

Your code never recurses.

```
for i in range(2):
    if len([0])>=1:
        print([0]+[i])
    else:
        return f([0]+[i])
# de-functified
```

First time through the `for` loop, `len([0]) >= 1` is `True`, so it prints `[0] + [0]`. Second time through the `for` loop, `len([0]) >= 1` is still `True`, so it prints `[0] + [1]`. Then the loop ends and control passes outside the function. You never reach your recursive case (`len(l) < 1`)

Note that your intended result is just:

```
import itertools

result = itertools.product(range(2), repeat=2)  # cast to list if necessary
```

Answer (score 0):

**DEBUGGING**

Let's put in a little debugging trace:

```
def f(l):
    print ("ENTER:", l)
    for i in range(2):
        print("i=", i, "len(l)=", len(l))
        if len(l)>=1:
            print(l+[i])
        else:
            return f(l+[i])

print(f([0]))
```

Output:

```
ENTER: [0]
i= 0 len(l)= 1
[0, 0]
i= 1 len(l)= 1
[0, 1]
None
```

**ANALYSIS**

You call the function with a one-element list.  Thus, **len(l)** is 1.  You take the "true" branch of the **if** both times through the loop.  Note that you never change the list **l**.  Therefore, you never make the recursive call you seem to expect.

**REPAIR**

I can't fix this for you, as you haven't explained the logic behind your expectation that **l[0]** will change to 1.  You never assign to that element, nor do you reconstruct **l** through whole-object assignment or the argument to the recursive call.